# recounting the rationals typo

Tags: rational-numbers

In [recounting the rationals](https://www.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/website/recounting.pdf). Is this statement a typo:

> Finally, the rightmost
> vertex of each row has denominator 1, as does the leftmost vertex of the next row, proving the
> claim.
> [image: The tree of fractions]

Did they mean "the numerator of the leftmost vertex of the next row". I'm pretty sure I'm wrong since this is such a popular paper but I don't see how.

Comment: Yes, that is their intention, esp when you bear in mind the claim is "the denominator of each fraction is the numerator of its successor".

Comment: @Calvin Lin thanks